# bind datatable to gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i have a stored procedure which return the following table for each user.
if a user selected the rolename in category item then it the selected value is y otherwise n

```
id    CategoryID  CategoryName RoleName Selected
-------------------------------------------
1    1            Category1        Create        y
2    2            Category2        Create         y
3    3            Category3         Create        y
4     1            Category1        Edit        n
5     2            Category2        Edit         y
6     3            Category3        Edit        n
7     1            Category1        Delete        y
8     2            Category2        Delete         n
9     3            Category3        Delete        n
```

I need to bind this to gridview as below, need to fill the column names and values(create, edit, delete) from sp and if y then select the checkbox.

```
Category1               Category2               Category3    
------------------------------------------------
[checkbox]Create        [checkbox]Create        [checkbox]Create    
[checkbox]Edit          [checkbox]Edit           [checkbox]Edit    
[checkbox]Delete        [checkbox]Delete        [checkbox]Delete
```

how do I bind the gridview?

Comment: A Gridview is intended for tabular data and is not really meant to be arranged in this way.  A FormView set to EditMode would be better suited to the task.  To do the equivalent with a Gridview would be far more complicated.